# How do i get specific value from a json data (api) using axios in vue

Tags: json, rest, vue.js, axios

my json data

```
[ { "status": 200, "values": [ { "total_transaction": 7, "total_deposit": 4, "total_withdrawal": 3, "total_request": 4, "accepted_request": 1, "pending_request": 0 } ] } ]
```

my axios script

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import dashboardData from '@/services/dashboard.service'

var dataValue = []

export default {
  name: 'DashboardInfo',
  data () {
    return {
      infoTiles: [{
        color: 'success',
        value: dataValue,
        text: 'Total Transaction',
        icon: '',
      }, {
        color: 'danger',
        value: dataValue,
        text: 'Deposit',
        icon: '',
      }, {
        color: 'info',
        value: dataValue,
        text: 'Withdrawal',
        icon: '',
      }],
    }
  },
  created(){
    axios
    .get('/dashboard')
    .then(response => (response.data))
    .then(result => {
      dataValue.push(result)
      document.getElementByName('total_transaction')
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

expectation outcome :

```
value : 7
text : total transaction

value : 4
text : total deposit

and so on...
```

for now my actual output is the json raw data with the status, values etc.
what should i code so i only get the number 7 for example instead of all of the data.

i know what iam doing is wrong since im really a beginner in this matter and its my first app i made using axios-vue.

Comment: That's why you should learn plain javascript before using frameworks like vue.

Comment: okay, but thats not what i was asking

Comment: where do you want to store that expecation outcome  ?

Comment: You should do `response.data.values` instead of `response.data` as for now when you push result to dataValue you are pushing whole json object

Comment: are you using someone else's code and you want to modify this code. right?
(your answer will help to answer your question.)

Comment: @hasan05 nope its mine, i just mish mash everything ive learn so far

Answer (score 0):

As I assumed, your json data is always like this.

```
[ { "status": 200, "values": [ { "total_transaction": 7, "total_deposit": 4, "total_withdrawal": 3, "total_request": 4, "accepted_request": 1, "pending_request": 0 } ] } ]
```

you have to modify your code on axios response. The code may solve your problem.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import dashboardData from '@/services/dashboard.service'

var dataValue = []

export default {
  name: 'DashboardInfo',
  data () {
    return {
      infoTiles: [{
        color: 'success',
        value: 0,
        text: 'Total Transaction',
        icon: '',
      }, {
        color: 'danger',
        value: 0,
        text: 'Total Deposit',
        icon: '',
      }, {
        color: 'info',
        value: 0,
        text: 'Total Withdrawal',
        icon: '',
      }, {
        color: 'info',
        value: 0,
        text: 'Total Request',
        icon: '',
      }, {
        color: 'info',
        value: 0,
        text: 'Accepted Request',
        icon: '',
      }, {
        color: 'info',
        value: 0,
        text: 'Pending Request',
        icon: '',
      }],
    }
  },
  created(){
    var that = this;
    axios
    .get('/dashboard')
    .then(response => (response.data))
    .then(result => {
      var values = result.data.values;
      var infoTiles = that.infoTiles;
      infoTiles[0].value = values['total_transaction'] ? values['total_transaction'] : 0;
      infoTiles[1].value = values['total_deposit'] ? values['total_deposit'] : 0;
      infoTiles[2].value = values['total_withdrawal'] ? values['total_withdrawal'] : 0;
      infoTiles[3].value = values['total_request'] ? values['total_request'] : 0;
      infoTiles[4].value = values['accepted_request'] ? values['accepted_request'] : 0;
      infoTiles[5].value = values['pending_request'] ? values['pending_request'] : 0;
      that.$set(that, 'infoTiles', infoTiles);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `that.$set(that.)` ? I think you have missed something

Answer (score 0):

Alright i kinda found a way around this.
this is what i did

```
mounted(){
    axios
    .get('/dashboard')
    .then(response => (response.data.values[0].total_transaction))
    .then(result => {
      dataValue.push(result)
    })
```

output i get

```
[7]
total transaction
```

i just have to push every response to a single var dedicated for each object.

i know its not the most effective way to do it, but it works